# Page jumps to top when scrolling down

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, visual-composer

Check out the page http://www.slide-art.com/get-inspired/ .
When scrolling down after the page is loaded, it jumps back to the top. I've tried scrolling down slowly and fast.

It only happens once, after it has jumped back to the top the problem is gone. I use a existing theme (Mr. Tailor) with Visual Composer. I haven't changed anything in the code (yet).

Can someone help me out? What could be the problem... and what could be the solution?

Comment: I think this is because of your snap slider. It is expecting the content to be within the indivudal `<li>` blocks of the `<ul class="main-slider">` section. You've used for the "first section" but the other sections aren't within that main-slider context so it's snapping back.

Comment: Still couldn't find exactly what was going wrong, but I've found the solution :) Thanks for pointing out where I should look